# Can't run jUnit with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, debugging

I use new Eclipse. Create demo test with jUnit (I added default jUnit library built-in Eclipse). Then I write this code:

```
import junit.framework.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class SimpleTest extends TestCase { 
   public SimpleTest(String name) { 
      super(name);
   }
   public final void main(String method){

   }

   @Test
   public final void testSimpleTest() {
      int answer = 2;
      assertEquals((1+1), answer); 
   }
}
```

But it doesn't run. In the Debug tab:

```
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner at localhost:52754 
Thread [main] (Suspended (exception ClassNotFoundException)) 
URLClassLoader$1.run() line: not available [local variables unavailable] 
AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedExceptionAction<T>, AccessControlContext) line: not available [native method] 
Launcher$AppClassLoader(URLClassLoader).findClass(String) line: not available 
Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line: not available 
Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(String, boolean) line: not available 
Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String) line: not available
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You, as many people, have confused the JUnit 3 and JUnit 4. 
If you are using JUnit 3 name your tests "test*" and inherit from TestCase.
If you are using JUnit 4 use annotations.

Comment: While this is true, this is not the *root cause* of this problem. Copypaste yourself, put a breakpoint on `ClassNotFoundException` and run in debug. You see, exactly the same problem until breakpoint is removed.

Comment: Nice to know the difference between the two versions.

Comment: How to do that?

I write new code:

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SimpleTest {
   @Test
   public final void abcTest() {
      int answer = 2;
      assertEquals((1+1), answer); 
   }
}

But it's still error

Comment: @KimKha that should run properly (tried it), can you give the exception? Make sure you have JUnit 4 in dependencies.

Comment: @KimKha I also tried your original example and it works (although it is a v3 and v4 mix). I tried fixing it (removed TestCase supr class and super constructor call) and I only got problem with having a constructor, but after deletion worked like a charm. Another thing which comes to my mind is if you are running it like a JUnit Test or Java application. In Eclipse you should run the test using Alt+Shift+X,T .

Comment: I used default jUnit4 in Eclipse. When I press Alt+Shift+X,T. It fired error: Could not find the main class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner. Program will exit

Comment: @KimKha seems like something with classpath/classloader, definitely not my thing...

Answer (score 6):

Remove the breakpoints on Exceptions when running in debug mode, or just run in non-debug mode.

In the debug view, on the right top box click the *Breakpoints* tab and **uncheck** any breakpoint on an `Exception`, e.g. `ClassNotFoundException` and rerun the test.

Comment: I have no breakpoint. And when I run in non-debug mode, it says 

Could not find the main class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner. Program will exit.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks (again). While it may not have helped KimKha, that solved the debug-mode-only problem I was having.